# Segmentation fault on default constructor

Tags: c++, class, pointers

When I run my code i get a segmentation fault for calling the default constructor, but not every time I call it. It faults when I try to dynamically allocate new memory after overloading the + operator. I know seg faults happen with misuse of pointers but I call the def. constructor prior in the code and it works.

[here](https://github.com/MarkFuller1/Project_1.5) is a git repo with main and header if needed:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "proj1-5-MyString.h"
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

    MyString::MyString() {
        capacity = 10;
        size = 0;
        data = new char[capacity];
        data[size] = '\0';
    }

//Constructor

MyString::MyString(const char *input) {
    this->capacity = 10;
    this->size = 0;
    this->data = new char[this->capacity];
    for (int count = 0; input[count] != '\0'; count++) {
        if (count >= this->capacity) {
            this->capacity *= 2;
            char *temp = new char[this->capacity];
            for (int i = 0; i < this->size; i++) {
                temp[i] = this->data[i];
            }
            delete[] this->data;
            this->data = temp;
            delete[] temp;
        }
        this->data[count] = input[count];
        this->size = count + 1;
    }
while ((double) this->size < 0.25 * ((double) (this->capacity))) {
    this->capacity = (int)floor(this->capacity / 2);
}

this->data[this->size + 1] = '\0';
}

//Constructor with an initialization character string

MyString::~MyString() {
    delete[] this->data;
    data = NULL;
}


//Destructor
MyString::MyString(const MyString &that) {
    this->data = new char[this->capacity];
    this->capacity = that.capacity;
    this->size = that.size;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        this->data[i] = that.data[i];
    }

    while(this->size < 0.25 * (double)(this->capacity)){
        this->capacity = (int)((double)that.capacity / 2.0);
    }

}

//Copy constructor
MyString &MyString::operator=(const MyString &input) {
    if (this->data != input.data) {
        delete[] this->data;
        this->capacity = input.capacity;
        this->size = input.size;

        int charCount = 0;
        for ( charCount; charCount < input.size; charCount++) {
            if (charCount >= this->capacity) {
                this->capacity *= 2;
                char *temp = new char[this->capacity];

                for (int j = 0; j < charCount; j++) {
                    temp[j] = this->data[j];
                }
                delete[] this->data;
                this->data = temp;
                delete[] temp;
            }
            this->data[charCount] = input.data[charCount];
            this->size = charCount + 1;
        }
    }

    return *this;
}

//Overloaded assignment operator, make a copy of MyString object
bool MyString::operator==(const MyString &otherString) const {
    int i = 0;
    bool same = true;

    if (this->size == otherString.size) {
        while (i < otherString.size) {
            if (this->data[i] == otherString.data[i]) {
                same = i <= size;
            } else {
                same = false;
            }
            i++;
        }
    } else {
        same = false;
    }
    return same;
}

//overloaded equivalence relational operator
char &MyString::operator[](int val) {
    return this->data[val];
}

//overloaded [ ] should return a char by reference
void MyString::operator+=(const MyString &otherStr) {
    *this = *this + otherStr;
}

//overloaded += operator, use to concatenate two MyStrings
MyString MyString::operator+(const MyString &otherStr) const {
```

//SEGFAULT HERE

```
MyString doubleString;
    cout << doubleString.capacity << endl;
    while (doubleString.capacity < (this->size + otherStr.size)) {
        doubleString.capacity *= 2;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < max(this->size, otherStr.size); i++) {
        doubleString.data[i] = this->data[i];
        doubleString.data[i + this->size] = otherStr.data[i];

    }

    doubleString.size = this->size + otherStr.size;
    return doubleString;
}

//Create a new MyString object that is the concatenation of two MyString
//objects
void MyString::getline(istream &in, char delimit) {
    delimit = '\n';
    int size = 10;
    char buffer[size];
    int charNum = 0;
    while (in.get(buffer[charNum++])) {
        if (buffer[charNum - 1] == delimit) {
            break;
        }
        if (charNum >= size) {
            char *temp = new char[size * 2];
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                temp[j] = data[j];
            }
            delete[] data;
            data = temp;
            delete[] temp;
        }
    }
}

//reads an entire line from a istream. Lines are terminated with delimit
//which is newline ‘\n’ by default
int MyString::length() const {
    return this->size;
}

//return the length of the string
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, MyString &stringWord) {
    for (int i = 0; i < stringWord.size; i++) {
        out << stringWord.data[i];
    }
    return out;
}
//overloaded insertion operator
```

Comment: can you post a small function that reproduces this problem? at least sometimes? also, what is the value of `this` when you get the segfault?

Answer (score 0):

For instance, if you have this code:

```
MyString s0 = "ABC";
MyString s1 = "DEF";

auto s2 = s0 + s1;
```

The first problem is in the constructor of `MyString`. Your strings are not `\0` terminated.

This can be fixed quite easiely though:

```
MyString::MyString(const char *input)
{
    this->capacity = 10;
    this->size = 0;
    //this->data = new char[this->capacity]; //<- Old
    this->data = new char[this->capacity](); //<- New
```

There are multiple places where you don't initialize the allocated char array. Please check your code and do so. Either via the `char()` constructor or various other ways (`std::fill`, `memset`, ...).

---

Please remember to debug your own code before posting a question. You can spot this in the debugger pretty easiely.